# search bar error when searching

Tags: swift, uitableview

when I perform a search in the search bar while the view is loading( loading the data from server)  I get error that auxiliar is nil.

```
var isSearch = false
var auxiliar : [Shops]!
var searchActive: Bool = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive
    {
        return auxiliar.count
    }
    return shops.count
   }
```

the data comes in JSON to the TableView

here is when I assign auxiliar

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    auxiliar = shops.filter { $0.shopname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil}
    if searchText == "" || searchBar.text == nil {
        auxiliar = shops
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `auxiliar`? I guess `numberOfRowsInSection` is called before the asynchorous network request could return, hence `auxiliar` is not set up and has the default `nil` value.

Comment: good question. Please check my question !!

Comment: Then how is shops defined and assigned a value to?

Comment: I think you should declare the `auxiliar` as `var auxiliar = [Shops]()` and if you want it to be optional then you should do it this way: `var auxiliar: [Shops]? = [Shops]()` then obviously you would have to change `auxiliar.count` to `auxiliar?.count`

Answer (score 1):

Declare `auxiliar` as an empty array.

```
var auxiliar = [Shops]()
```

When `auxiliar.count` is accessed by `tableView(_:, numberOfRowsInSection:)`, the `tableView` will be empty. Then, when you get the data and `searchBar(_:,textDidChange:)` is called, `auxiliar` is set again. When you reload the table, the new data is displayed.